# R: ggplot2 pointrange example

Tags: r, ggplot2, machine-learning

I am currently reading **R for Data Science** by Hadley Wickham. In that, there is the following example:

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
stat_summary(
    mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
    fun.ymin = min,
    fun.ymax = max,
    fun.y = median
)
```

Now, there is a question as how to create the same plot by using appropriate `geom_` function. I looked at the default `geom` for `stat_summary` and it is `pointrange`.

So I tried the following:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth), stat = "summary")
```

But I do not get the `min` and `max` points on the plot.

**How do I get the exact plot by using `geom_pointrange`?**

Comment: I'm also reading that book, and I had the exact same question. StackOverflow at its best.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`geom_pointrange` does not automatically compute the ymin or ymax values. You can do this with `stat = "summary"` while still using `geom_pointrange`:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
  geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
                  stat = "summary",
                  fun.ymin = min,
                  fun.ymax = max,
                  fun.y = median)
```

Comment: So all I was missing was the last 3 arguments.

Answer (score 9):

The easy way I can think of is just using geom_line and stat_summary

```
 ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth)) +
     geom_line() +
     stat_summary(fun.y = "median", geom = "point", size = 3)
```

This will give very similar plot. 
[image]

If I really want to use geom_pointrange, I would make small dataset first.

```
data = diamonds %>%
    group_by(cut) %>%
    summarise(min = min(depth), max = max(depth), 
        median = median(depth))

ggplot(data, aes(x = cut, y = median, ymin = min, ymax = max)) + 
    geom_linerange() + 
    geom_pointrange()
```

This would generate the exact same plot. Hope this helps!
 [image]

Comment: Thank you. The first option looks good but the question states that t should without using `stat_summary`. Your second options is good too but it uses techniques which are taught in the later part of the book. So is there ay other way?

Answer (score 8):

I'm three years in the future and I was with the same doubt, but none of the solutions here worked for me. I was able to achieve the desired output with this code (just to help the folks on my time):

```r
ggplot(data = diamonds) +
  geom_pointrange(
    mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
    stat = "summary",
    fun.min = min,
    fun.max = max,
    fun = median
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. The arguments must have been renamed at some point in the last three years. It does not even say this was deprecated  - ggplot2 3.3.0

Comment: No prob, mate! :D