# Plot min, max, median for each x value in geom_pointrange

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

So I know the better way to approach this is to use the `stat_summary()` function, but this is to address a question presented in Hadley's R for Data Science book mostly for my own curiosity. It asks how to convert code for an example plot made using `stat_summary()` to make the same plot with `geom_pointrange()`. The example is:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds) + 
  stat_summary(
    mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth),
    fun.ymin = min,
    fun.ymax = max,
    fun.y = median
  )
```

And the plot should look like this:

[image: pointrange plot]
<sub>(source: [had.co.nz](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/visualize_files/figure-html/unnamed-chunk-35-1.png))</sub>

I've attempted with code such as:

```
ggplot(data = diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, y = depth)) +
  geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = min(depth), ymax = max(depth)))
```

[image]

However, this plots the min and max for *all* depth values across each cut category (i.e., all `ymin`'s and `ymax`'s are the same). I also tried passing a vector of mins and maxs, but `ymin` only takes single values as far as I can tell. It's probably something simple, but I think people mostly use `stat_summary()` as I've found very few examples of `geom_pointrange()` usage via Google.

Comment: Good question. I think a lot of people scratch their heads over that one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: ggplot2 pointrange example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850568/r-ggplot2-pointrange-example)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need to do the summary outside the plot function to use `geom_pointrange`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
summary_diamonds <- diamonds %>% 
    group_by(cut) %>% 
    summarise(lower = min(depth), upper = max(depth), p = median(depth))

ggplot(data = summary_diamonds, mapping = aes(x = cut, y = p)) +
    geom_pointrange(mapping = aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this worked great! Comparing the two, `stat_summary` seems more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

`geom_pointrange` includes a `stat` argument, so you can do the statistical transformation inline https://stackoverflow.com/a/41865061